# How to clear all fields (not reset) with redux-form?

Tags: forms, redux-form

I have a simple redux form initialized with not empty data. There are three buttons: save, reset, clear. I need to clear all values on clicking on "Clear" button with ability to restore defaults when clicked on "Reset" btn (i.e. persist initialValues). What is the best way to do it?

```
dispatch(destroy(formName))
```

works, but initial values are deleted, so there is no way to reset form  with initialValues, since it is simply destroyed.

```
dispatch(reset(formName))
```

works only if the form was initialized with no data.

Expected: to have ability to clear all fields values of the form with ability to restore initialValues.

Comment: Can you just save the initial values to some variable and load it again later on? Have you checked if this example https://redux-form.com/8.2.0/examples/initializefromstate/ implements what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes that will work.